# Internal REST API security

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, security, rest

I have been looking into this for a few days now and come across many SO questions but still I am not so sure.

I am creating an REST API with Node.js which will be used for a web app and a mobile app which is only intended for the app's back-end to use and not for other developers.

My current concerns are security I know there are other ways such as OAuth etc but I am wondering if my current method is secure enough.

The "client" creates a HMAC-SHA1 token using the `crypto.createHmac('text', 'secret');` method in Node which contains an API key along with a secret. The secret is built into the code while the API key has been previously retrieved from the DB when the user logged into the app. The client then sends this token as well as the user ID.

The REST server then retrieves the API key of the user ID that has been sent and then creates a HMAC-SHA1 token, again with the API key it just retrieved and a secret. It then checks they are both equal and moves on with the request.

I don't mind if it is "reinventing the wheel" or whatever, its more for experience too. If this method is insecure, I'd like to know why.

Comment: I'm not sure the HMAC step is even necessary. Unless you expect intruders to be able to eavesdrop on your presumably encrypted server-to-server communication, why not just send your shared secret and API token as part of the message?

Comment: @AndrewLavers Yeah I was wondering if hmac was even needed, it was just something i saw popping up a few times while I was researching. Just that the topic is highly opinionated and its hard to find what is actually needed as opposed to over-cautioning.

Comment: @AndrewLavers Although I am wondering seeing as it will be accessed by a mobile app too, would they be able to read the shared secret then?

Comment: If I understand your topology correctly, mobile app connects to backend service A, and backend service A connects to your secure REST API B. So A and B share a secret that the mobile app isn't privy to. Do I have that right?

Comment: No the mobile app would connect to the api directly. There is a web app but thats just another platform also connecting to the api. Is this bad?

Comment: That's bad because your scheme would require the mobile app to have the shared secret, hash or no hash. You might want to rephrase your question to be clearer/more specific.

Comment: @AndrewLavers Hmm, I havent seen anything about mobiles having to connect to a seperate backend out of the countless videos/articles i've seen on rest design although it does make sense.
Seeing as you've said that though, my question _now_ is how would I go about authentication for an API being accessed by both browser and mobile apps? Would oAuth work?

Comment: I think http://security.stackexchange.com/ is the right place for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without physical security of the client device (ie: you own the hardware) there is no perfect security. Someone who owns the client device will always be able to find your secret so don't worry about it too much. Use your HMAC to obscure the secret from a network proxy.

Even with OAUTH the client key can be stolen.

You can provide security for users by requiring authentication. It sounds like you are already doing that. So I think you're good.

That said, as a general rule I prefer using existing protocols and libraries than implementing your own. They tend to have more secure implementations.